# PHP: View not getting select values from model

Tags: php, mysql

I am sure I'll get lots of comments on how I am doing things; I do this part-time and trying to develop new system using MVC.  Here is my current issue: When I load a form (view), my controller calls my model file, which immediately instantiates a new model for the view and retrieves old form values from MySQL db.  The view has a bunch of dropdowns. I load the values from the db into model private variables, which have the same name as in the view, but the values are not being passed into the view, so the dropdowns are all showing their default values -- they should be showing the values stored in the db.  Code below, but just relevant snippets:

```
<?php
require_once("../controller/db_conn_ctlr.php");

class dom_leader_model {
    // Variables
    private $ldr1_rec;  // leader 1 record
    private $ldr1_role; // leader 1 role
    private $ldr2_rec;  // leader 2 record
    private $ldr2_role; // leader 2 role
    private $ldr3_rec;  // leader 3 record
    private $ldr3_role; // leader 3 role
    private $ldr4_rec;  // leader 3 record
    private $ldr4_role; // leader 3 role    
    private $trail_no;  // TRAIL # of plan

    // constructor
    public function __construct() {
        $trail_no = $this->getTrailNumber();
        $this->getOldLeaderInfo($trail_no);
    }

    // get TRAIL number
    public function getTrailNumber() {
        return $this->trail_no = $_SESSION['trail_no'];
    }

    // get leader info from database and put it on the form
    public function getOldLeaderInfo($trail_no) {

        $fiscal_yr = substr($trail_no, 0, 2);
        $trip_id = substr ($trail_no, 2, 3);
        $section_id = substr($trail_no, 5, 1);

        $query20 = "
            SELECT * FROM leader_info
            WHERE fiscal_yr = '$fiscal_yr' AND trip_id = '$trip_id'
                AND section_id = '$section_id'";

        $connect = db_connection();    
        $result20 = mysqli_query($connect, $query20) or die("Query20 failed: 
             " . mysqli_error($connect));
        $connect->close();

        if($result20) {
            $row = $result20->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $this->ldr1_rec = $row['leader1_record'];         
            $this->ldr1_role = $row['leader1_role'];
            $this->ldr2_rec = $row['leader2_record'];
            $this->ldr2_role = $row['leader2_role']; 
            $this->ldr3_rec = $row['leader3_record'];
            $this->ldr3_role = $row['leader3_role'];
            $this->ldr4_rec = $row['leader4_record'];
            $this->ldr4_role = $row['leader4_role'];            
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }        
    }

[from controller]
<?php
require_once '../model/dom_leader_model.php';
require_once '../utilities/check_info_saved.php';
$session_start = session_start();

$leaderInfoModel = new dom_leader_model();
$trail_no = $leaderInfoModel->getTrailNumber();


if (isset($_POST['save']) || isset($_POST['next'])) {   

[from view]
<p>Leader 1 Information:</p>
<?php
    if (empty($ldr1_rec)) {
        $ldr1_switch = 'Select Leader';
        echo '<select name="ldr1_rec"><option selected 
            value="">',$ldr1_switch,'</option>',
            require("../../lists/leader_list.txt"),'</select>';
    } else {
        $ldr1_switch = leader_switch($ldr1_rec, 'dom');         
        echo '<select name="ldr1_rec"><option selected 
            value="',$ldr1_rec,'">',$ldr1_switch,'</option>',
            require("../../lists/leader_list.txt"),'</select>'; 
    }

    if (empty($ldr1_role)) {
        $role1 = "Select Role";
        echo '<select name="ldr1_role"><option selected 
            value="">',$role1,'</option>',
            require("../../lists/staff_role_list.txt"),'</select>';
    } else {    
        $role1 = role_switch($ldr1_role);
        echo '<select name="ldr1_role"><option selected 
            value="',$ldr1_role,'">',$role1,'</option>',
            require("../../lists/staff_role_list.txt"), '</select>&nbsp;';
     }
?><p><hr>
```

Like I said, I do this part-time and I am sure many of you will see better ways of writing the code, but what I am really looking for is an answer for why my values retrieved from the database are not getting to the form when it loads.

Thanks in advance.

John C.

Comment: not fetching through all code, but did you just try `selected="selected"`instead of just `select` -> `<option value="',$ldr1_role,'" selected="selected">',$role1,'</option>`  ?

Comment: my mistake -> read ` *selected* instead of just 'select' `

Answer (score 0):

You should use `selected="selected"` instead of just `select`
ie: `<option value="',$ldr1_role,'" selected="selected">',$role1,'</option>`

Although `select` is correct for a browser, it might be sometimes rejected (this happened to me with PHP a couple of weeks ago, helping/working on someone's else code).

`selected="selected"` is valid for all doctypes too AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks but that is not it; part of the problem is in the model, the values I want the view to see are declared private, so I either have to declare them public or create a public get method for each value.  John C.